# ArcGIS If/Else with calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, round-function

I am seeking to calculate the variable MASSSTAB through rounding the variable LAENGE and doing some basic math.

My codeblock currently looks like this:

```
x = long(round(!LAENGE!, -1))

def ifBlock(m, x, a= 50, b= 30):  
  if x > 10 :
    m= ( x * b )
  else:
    m= ( x * a )
  return m
```

My Codeblock is:

```
enter code here
```

There is already a syntax error (parsing error) in the first line. Do I have to define "x" in another way?

Comment: could you add a screenschot? because you use 2 times the term codeblock and I don't know if its now empty or not

Comment: Move the first line inside the function but before your `if`. If `m` is what is being returned it does not need to be an input into your function.

Answer (score 2):

Your x is currently defined by a fieldname instead of a variable. Within the codeblock, use variables which you pass within the expression. Also, you don't need to define "m" in the function definition.

e.g.
codeblock:

```
def ifBlock(x1, a= 50, b= 30):
  x = long(round(x1, -1))  
  if x > 10 :
    m= ( x * b )
  else:
    m= ( x * a )
  return m
```

expression:
`MASSSTAB = ifBlock(!LAENGE!)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line expression if you want to avoid using the codeblock to define a function:

```
long(round(!LAENGE!, -1)) * [50, 30][round(!LAENGE!, -1) > 10]
```

What this does is round the value of your variable and then multiplies it by either 30 or 50, depending on whether the rounded value is greater than 10 or not. This works because the Boolean expression `round(!LAENGE!, -1) > 10` evaluates to `True` or `False`, which are equal to `1` and `0`, respectively. The `1` or `0` then serves as a positional index for the list `[50, 30]`.